# c program with weird output

Tags: c, arrays

I have relatively good experience with c programming. It has been one of my favorite languages. Today while studying about shell programming, I came across a c program that I executed on my Linux system (Backtrack 5 r2). And the program had a strange output, that I really couldn't figure out.

Here's the code...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char array[] = { 0x25, 115, 0 };
    char array2[] = { 68, 0x61, 118, 0x69, 0144, 040,
                      0107, 97, 0x74, 119, 0157, 0x6f,
                      100, 0x20, 0x72, 117, 'l', 0x65,
                      115, 041, 012, 0 };

    printf(array, array2);
}
```

Compiled this code using gcc and on execution got the output as

> David Gatwood rules!

Couldn't really understand how and why did I get this output. As per my knowledge, passing the name of an array to 'printf' would simply print the base address of the array, i.e. the address of the 0th element of the array. And this too would be properly displayed only when the proper format specifier is used in the 'printf' statement.

So where am I going wrong or am I overlooking something important or is it because of the gcc?

Comment: format string, string.  Nothing more than that

Comment: format string...??? how ...?? what is 0x25,115,0 ???

Comment: 0x25  == '%'    ......

Comment: And remember that `012` is in octal and represents the number `10`.

Comment: oh ok.... shit... so lame of me.. i just did not realize it... thanks guys... sorted it out... !! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program is just an obfuscated way to write

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char array[] = { '%', 's', '\0' };
    char array2[] = { 'D', 'a', 'v', 'i', 'd', ' ', ..., '\0' };

    printf(array, array2);
}
```

Since printf expects as the format a string, and an array name used in an expression like this is treated as ("decays", although this term is not official standardese) a pointer to its first element, everything is proper. In fact, the initializations are equivalent to

```
char *array = "%s";
char *array2 = "David ...";
```

with the exception that the latter are not writable (because string literals are read-only in C).

And no, passing an array to printf (where exactly?) does not *print* its address. Printing an array address (or pointer) can only be done with the `%p` conversion specifier:

```
printf ("array/ptr address = %p\n", (void *)array);
```

Note that the `(void *)` cast is *required* to avoid undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Think of `array` as `"%s"`. Thus the `printf` prints a string.

```
ASCII 0x25: %
ASCII 115:  s
```

Same goes for `array2`. I'm not sure why the author mixes decimal hex and octal though.

Answer (score 0):

what else would you expect when you do `printf("%s", "David Gatwood rules!");`
As you've wrote, that you have experience with c, you should have also seen pointers to char array with characters used as c strings.